# Why is dynamic array failing with larger numbers?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, segmentation-fault

So I was solving this practice code of Hackerrank:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/dynamic-array

Where in short, I am supposed to implement a program that in short implements and manipulates a dynamic array.

So I wrote this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef long long int LLT;
int main()
{
    int n = 0, q = 0, temp = 0,newSize = 1;
    LLT x = 0, y = 0, lastAns = 0, inx = 0;
    scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);

    // Allocating a multidimensional array.
    LLT **seqList = (LLT**) malloc(sizeof(LLT*) * n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        seqList[i] = (LLT*) malloc(sizeof(LLT));
        seqList[i][0] = 1; // Setting the size of the array.
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < q; i++){
        scanf("%d %lld %lld", &temp, &x, &y);
        inx = (x ^ lastAns) % n;
        if(temp == 1){
            seqList[inx][0] += 1;
            newSize = seqList[inx][0];
            LLT* buffer = (LLT*) realloc(seqList[inx], newSize * sizeof(LLT));
            if (buffer == NULL){
                free(seqList[inx]);
                return NULL;
            }
            seqList[inx] = buffer;
            seqList[inx][newSize - 1]  = y;

       }
        else{
            lastAns = seqList[inx][(y % (seqList[inx][0])) + 1];
            printf("%d\n", lastAns);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the correct answer for small test cases, for example:

```
INPUT: 
2 5
1 0 5
1 1 7
1 0 3
2 1 0
2 1 1

OUTPUT:
7
3
```

But with large input like this:

INPUT: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24182668/

OUTPUT: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24182670/

It gives an error. A segmentation fault.
So I debugged it and found the error was occurring with this line 21:

```
seqList[inx][0] += 1;
```

After this input:

```
2 212195438 191367377
```

Why is it happening? What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE 1:**

***Your comments were very helpful and I updated the code accordingly.***

Updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
typedef unsigned long long int LLT;
int main()
{
LLT x = 0, y = 0, lastAns = 0, inx = 0, n = 0, q = 0, temp = 0, newSize = 1;
scanf("%llu %llu", &n, &q);

// Allocating a multidimensional array.
LLT **seqList = (LLT**) malloc(sizeof(LLT*) * n);
if(seqList == NULL){
    free(seqList);
    printf("Couldn't allocate memory.");
    return 432;
}
for(LLT i = 0; i < n; i++){
    seqList[i] = (LLT*) malloc(sizeof(LLT));
    if(seqList[i] == NULL){
        free(seqList[i]);
        printf("Couldn't allocate memory.");
        return 432;
    }
    seqList[i][0] = 1; // Setting the size of the array.
}

for(LLT i = 0; i < q; i++){
    scanf("%llu %llu %llu", &temp, &x, &y);
    inx = (x ^ lastAns) % n;
    if(temp == 1){
        assert(inx >= 0);
        seqList[inx][0] += 1;
        newSize = seqList[inx][0];
        LLT* buffer = (LLT*) realloc(seqList[inx], newSize * sizeof(LLT));
        if (buffer == NULL){
            free(seqList[inx]);
            printf("Couldn't allocate memory.");
            return 432;
        }
        seqList[inx] = buffer;
        seqList[inx][newSize - 1]  = y;

   }
    else{
        lastAns = seqList[inx][(y % (seqList[inx][0])) + 1];
        printf("%llu\n", lastAns);
    }
}
}
```

It doesn't break anymore but still gives wrong answer for the test cases I have used when I first posted the question.

Test case:

INPUT: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24182668/

EXPECTED OUTPUT: http://paste.ubuntu.com/24182670/

Please point out the mistake I am making.

TIA.

Comment: Debug tip: insure `scanf("%d %lld %lld", &temp, &x, &y)` succeeds --> `if(scanf("%d %lld %lld", &temp, &x, &y) != 3) break;`  AFAIK, `q` is too great.

Comment: Unclear that `inx = (x ^ lastAns) % n;` results _always_ in a non-negative answer.  `x ^ lastAns` may be negative leading to negative `inx`.    Suggest `assert(inx >= 0); seqList[inx][0] += 1;`  Why use signed math when all is non-negative values? Array indexing should be `size_t` BTW.

Comment: You don't even check if you really get a memory block. Use the debugger.

Comment: True, no check after, `scanf("%d %d", &n, &q);, malloc(sizeof(LLT*) * n);,  seqList[i] = (LLT*) malloc(sizeof(LLT)); scanf("%d %lld %lld", &temp, &x, &y)`  Although these are basic checks, good to do them before posting.

Comment: Of course if `int` is 16-bit - code will not work.

Comment: I suspect `malloc(sizeof(LLT*) * n);` is return `NULL` for large `n` and codes fails to check.

Comment: Thankyou for you comments, I have updated the code and posted please check it out and point out the mistake, it still didn't solve the entire problem but fixed alot of it.